# Bootstrap 4 modal with scrollable body and non-fixed header height

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've seen several solutions on SO and a few blogs on how to make the body of a Bootstrap modal scrollable. The problem is that these solutions require the modal header to be a fixed height.

In my case, I have text that displays in the modal header that varies in length depending on what the user clicks. I can't use a fixed header height because I need the header to be responsive to the text.

Basically I want the modal header to be able to take up as much room as it needs and the modal body height will get smaller accordingly so that the whole modal dialog fits on the screen.

Is there any way to pre-compute the modal header height **before** displaying it? If I could do that then I could simply use jQuery to change the height of the modal body accordingly.

Alternatively, is there a CSS solution to this problem?

Below is my HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="abstract-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="abstract-modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header stylish-color" id="modal-header">
                <!-- Modal Title -->
                <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title white-text font-weight-bold py-1"></h4>
                <!-- Modal Colour -->
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                <!-- Publisher -->
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <div class="col flush-labels">
                        <h5><span id="modal-publisher" class="badge orange"></span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Date Published -->
                    <div class="col flush-labels no-left-padding">
                        <h5><span id="modal-published-date" class="badge stylish-color"></span></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Authors Name -->
                <h5>Authors</h5>
                <p id="modal-authors"></p>
                <h5>Abstract</h5>
                <!-- Abstract -->
                <p id="modal-abstract"></p>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer flex-center" id="modal-footer">
                <!-- Publisher Link Out Button -->
                <a id="modal-publisher-link-out" href="#" target="_blank">
                    <button type="button" class="btn stylish-color">Publisher's Site<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt ml-2"></i></button>
                </a>
                <!-- Add to Search Button -->
                <button id="add-to-refine-button" type="button" class="btn peach-gradient" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Add to search<i class='fas fa-plus-square ml-2'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.modal {
  /* Enable smooth-scrolling on iOS */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.modal .modal-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-content {
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-header {
  /* can't have a fixed height here */
}

.modal-body {
  /* how to set modal-body height? */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Any help here is appreciated!

Comment: where is trigger button of model ?

Comment: The user clicks on a D3 node, the modal fields are then modified using jQuery and the modal is shown using `$("#abstract-modal").modal("show")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using css flex.

We set the modal-content height to 90% view height (or whatever you want it to be)

.modal-header set to not grow or shrink

```
flex: 0 0 auto;
```

.modal-footer set to not grow or shrink

```
flex: 0 0 auto;
```

```css
.modal-content {
  height: 90vh;
}

.modal-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.modal-body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#abstract-modal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="abstract-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-flex" id="abstract-modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header stylish-color" id="modal-header">
          <!-- Modal Title -->
          <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title white-text font-weight-bold py-1">Super long title that makes the header taller</h4>
          <!-- Modal Colour -->
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                    </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

          <!-- Publisher -->
          <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="col flush-labels">
              <h5><span id="modal-publisher" class="badge orange"></h5>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Date Published -->
                        <div class="col flush-labels no-left-padding">
                            <h5><span id="modal-published-date" class="badge stylish-color"></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Authors Name -->
                    <h5>Authors</h5>
                    <p id="modal-authors">Donec dictum elit et tellus rutrum consequat. Aenean imperdiet et urna quis placerat. Nulla ex nunc, fermentum ac velit sed, euismod convallis nulla. Morbi nibh massa, pulvinar sed velit vitae, luctus gravida orci. Curabitur pellentesque, sem vitae lobortis facilisis, tellus sapien finibus eros, eget maximus neque arcu sed diam. Donec ultricies lacinia leo nec convallis. Proin ut lacus dignissim, feugiat tellus in, semper ipsum. Nullam fermentum massa eu purus facilisis eleifend. Ut sit amet sem vel enim ullamcorper ultricies. Mauris sit amet egestas turpis. Nam eros velit, mattis ac gravida at, mollis quis velit. Integer eu tincidunt lacus, eu mollis sapien. Quisque rutrum dolor quis dui commodo, ac tempor magna commodo. Nullam semper, sem ut varius tempus, ex nibh placerat ex, quis tempor enim risus vitae turpis. Aenean sed erat bibendum, mollis turpis a, volutpat sem. Morbi id turpis in leo feugiat tempus.</p>
                    <h5>Abstract</h5>
                    <!-- Abstract -->
                    <p id="modal-abstract">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis a dignissim lacus. Pellentesque varius neque id augue accumsan, id hendrerit nisi vulputate. In nec magna nibh. Proin non iaculis ante. Proin ac elit erat. Praesent pellentesque mauris quis mauris tempus pellentesque. Fusce pulvinar nunc a risus finibus volutpat. Nam eget metus venenatis ligula pulvinar hendrerit viverra ac magna. Vivamus faucibus non felis ac convallis. Curabitur porta, nibh ac venenatis gravida, nisl dui auctor leo, vel blandit sapien justo at nunc.</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal Footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer flex-center" id="modal-footer">
                    <!-- Publisher Link Out Button -->
                    <a id="modal-publisher-link-out" href="#" target="_blank">
                        <button type="button" class="btn stylish-color">Publisher's Site<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt ml-2"></i></button>
                    </a>
                    <!-- Add to Search Button -->
                    <button id="add-to-refine-button" type="button" class="btn peach-gradient" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Add to search<i class='fas fa-plus-square ml-2'></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Man, this is amazing, only thing is that maybe a few things have to be fixed on the `footer`, since buttons go out of bounds.

Comment: There may be some customizing needed based on screen size etc

Comment: I modified my settings on header and footer to flex: 0 0 auto;  the footer does look odd in the snippet panel, but that size is quite small.

Comment: Yeah, in full screen it looks great

Comment: My footer is filling up space for some reason but I can mess around with it. Thanks for this, it solves my problem.

Comment: Something to note, looking at the bootstrap 4 css, modal-body already has flex: 1 1 auto; so that is not actually needed.I removed it from my example

Comment: @IvanS95 To fix the issue with the buttons out of bounds, you can set a min-height of .modal-content to x pixels to prevent the modal from completely collapsing.

Comment: Sounds about right, is these use cases that help a lot to learn about limitations and workarounds in CSS, great job man